# how can I download an png from server in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I get an qr-code png from server, and in network tab I can see the preview of image correctly.

[image: the preview of qr-code that i get from server]

in my coded if I log the response of this api, I get the bytes of image like bellow:

[image: the response's log that I get from server]

my question is how can I click a button and download this image with the info I have?

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: the `download` attribute might be what your looking for? `<a href="..." download>qr code</a>`?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Logging the response that contains an image won't display the image itself, as the console can't display it

Answer (score -1):

You may use the following code:

```
<script>
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'qr?item=xyz';
    link.download = 'Download.jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
</script>
```

Or using HTML5 you may use:

```
<a href="qr?item=xyz" download="QR file.gif">Download QR Code</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but with the response that I get from server(second image), it's impossible to use these codes

Comment: Do you mean that response appears in the "Response" tab or appears in the browser window?